# jQuery Scroll Current Position and Next-Prev Navigator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a bit of advice as I can't get my noob head around the following, please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NtUpw/

The code works as intended, but when the current div offset goes > 41 and prev is hit, I'd like the page to return to the beginning of the current div, not to one before that. Any idea how can I add this condition?

I realise the current code isn't the cleanest (actually it's a combination of two fiddles), but I hope someone could take a look at it anyway. Thanks.

```
$('a.buttons').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var t = $(this).text(),
    that = $(this);

if (t === 'next' && $('.current').next('div.post').length > 0 ) {
    var $next = $('.current').next('.post');
    var top = $next.offset().top;

    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.current').next('div.post').offset().top - 40

    });

} else if (t === 'prev' && $('.current').prev('div.post').length > 0 ) {
    var $prev = $('.current').prev('.post');
    var top = $prev.offset().top;

    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.current').prev('div.post').offset().top - 40
    });
}



$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    $('.post').each(function () {
        var post = $(this);
        var position = post.position().top - $(window).scrollTop();

        if (position <= 40) {

            post.addClass('current');
            post.prev().removeClass("current");

        } else {
            post.removeClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's odd, it works in Chrome but not FF.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2QYgR/1/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Edward, your tweak works like a charm, except on the first div. I also noticed the FF issue, wonder what could cause that...

Comment: Ok, fixed first div http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2QYgR/2/, what is the FF issue?

Comment: @jonyjameson Solved firefox issue too: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2QYgR/3/, I'll post as answer with explanation

Comment: Great! As Steve mentioned, the fiddle doesn't seem to work in FF, perhaps just an optimisation issue?

Comment: Fixed firefox issue too, look the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16132555/975520

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prev action works by moving always the div to the previous; the solution is to check the current position of the navigator respect to the current div:

```
var $prev;
var top;

var firstElem = true;
if ($('.current').prev('div.post').length > 0) {
    $prev = $('.current').prev('.post');
    top = $prev.offset().top;
    firstElem = false
}

var currTop = $('.current').offset().top;
var navBottom = $('.navigation').offset().top + 40;

if (currTop == navBottom && !firstElem) {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.current').prev('div.post').offset().top - 40
    });
```

with this the navigator jumps to the previous div only if is not at the top of the current; alternatively jumps to the previous.

The firefox issue depends on how Firefox places the overflow, it places it at the `html` level not at `body` like other browsers.
To let it work you must define the scrolling action with:

```
$('body,html').animate({

});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2QYgR/3/